# Read/write logic in IC8259

Tags: integrated-circuit, microprocessor

I was studying about 8259A from the Intel documentation of [Intel 8259A](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2010/readings/hardware/8259A.pdf). What I came across was that the Read/Write Logic has an input from control logic.In all other ICs that I have seen, this is shown the other way round. Plus, I see no output pins in the R/W logic block. So what is that input for? Or is it a typo?

[image: 8259A Block Diagram]

Comment: That is a 30 year old revision to a 40 year old datasheet. There is something very odd about studying it today. We like to think of electronics as a fast-moving, high tech industry, but really...

Comment: @BrianDrummond Actually we have a "8085/86 microprocessor and its interfacing" course in our undergrads. And I think its a pretty common course every where in India. So I cannot do pretty much about it. Plus that's like an official data sheet so have to study that. Plus most of the books I studied have just copied it down. So better to read the datasheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a rare ["write only"](http://repeater-builder.com/molotora/gontor/25120-bw.pdf) block that only has inputs and has no outputs.

Yes, it's a typo (or graphico).